# UIDatePicker valueChanged as wheels spin?

Tags: ios, uidatepicker

I’m using a `UIDatePicker` to update `UILabel` with a date, but I’m noticing that the `valueChanged` event is only called when the wheels stop spinning.

Ideally if the user flicks a column, I’d like the date in the label to update continuously as the wheel spins, for a realtime sense of feedback.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an extreme workaround, but...

If you use a UIPickerView instead of a UIDatePicker (which, granted, would entail re-implementing most of the DatePicker), you can detect the wheel spinning in the pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView: delegate method.  If there are more rows than can be displayed at once, this will be called every time the wheel moves.

Comment: Novel approach. Is the `UIDatePicker` really limited in that way? That's disappointing. But, looks like this is probably more work than I want to put in right now. Thanks for confirming!